# What does "bar the question" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I was asked what I was working on last night and I only have one thing to work on so the answer was pretty obvious but before I could respond he said, "bar the question?", which apparently means something like "Or should I not ask".
Is this true? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

To bar is to make an exception for. In wrestling *No holds barred* means that there are no exceptions for a hold. Any hold is valid. In craps, game of dice, there is a play of *Don't Pass Bar 12* meaning any non-pass score wins except twelve. (This area is often miss identified as the *Don't pass bar*)

When answering the question that is just what you are working on. A whimsical answer to the question would be, *"I'm working on an answer to your question."*
They wanted to know what you were doing besides talking and answering.

From Merriam-Webster for bar as a verb;
to set aside : to not take into consideration : to rule out or exclude

Comment: I can't quite follow this answer.  Can you cite your references?

Comment: While I agree with your answer as to what to "bar" something is, I don't think that's what the speaker was intending, I think the speaker is likely misinformed and "bar the question" doesn't mean what he thinks it means.